# Python: could a script compiled with py2exe freeze the operating system?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I am using **py2exe** to compiling python scripts in executable files on Windows Xp/7/2000.
I am wondering if such executable scripts could freeze the operating system, and I have to reboot Windows.
I suppose such problems could occur if I try to manage driver library.
What do you think about?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to write code that will crash your OS? Probably, yes. If you have administrator privileges then even more probably. (You could play "let's kill services until something stops working"...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, yes. Windows is not the most stable OS out there, and programs sometime "freeze" it even without mucking with drivers and kernel-mode code. Python programs aren't any different in this respect, whether packed with `py2exe` or not, since Python programs on Windows easily have access to the same Windows APIs any other program can access.

However, I have a feeling you're not "just asking" if you have a specific application freezing the system, it's something that should be addressed for the specific case in hand. Unless the application does something really crazy, it's probably a bug in it that can be solved.

Comment: I have no problem with my answers being downvoted, but I'd appreciate a reason stated in the comment, since I do want to understand where I'm wrong

Comment: *Windows is not the most stable OS out there, and programs sometime "freeze" it even without mucking with drivers and kernel-mode code*: **citation needed**. In the old 9x days, that was possible, but I'd love to hear at least one example of that being possible on Windows 7. I tried to answer myself and therefore removed the downvote

Comment: @phihag: based on experience, yes. I did have Windows 7 crash after running programs that didn't request admin priveleges. Granted, this happens *much* less than in Windows 98, but to say that it never ever happens is just naive.

Comment: Thank to all for sugeestion :)

Answer (score 0):

A Python program - regardless of whether iterpreted by the Python executable or in py2exe form - can do the same as any other program. That means that it should not be able to freeze a modern operating system unless it is run with superuser rights. However, programs (especially malicious and badly written ones) can significantly degrade user experience, for example by going fullscreen and refusing to show the desktop or starting lots of threads and processes.